# *ngFor iterate through array containing objects

Tags: angular, typescript

gemItems:

```
{
 A: [
{id: 5, commonName: "Abalone Pearls"},
{id: 3, commonName: "Abalone Shell"}
],
 B: [
{id: 41, commonName: "Barite"},
{id: 42, commonName: "Bastnaesite"}
]
}
```

HTML:

```
<div *ngFor = let items of gemItems>
<div>{{items.id}}</div>
</div>
```

Kindly let me know how to loop through gemItems.

Comment: `gemItems` is not even a valid json.

Comment: @NicholasK Instead of gemItems as array I kept as objects. Now working. Thanks.

Comment: @NicholasK Iam able to iterate through array, ie. getting A, B but not able to iterate through A and B. I have updated my question.

Comment: Maybe the answer I included below will help..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, the `getItems` should be defined as below: (the json in the question is not valid)

```
  getItems = [
    {
      A: [
        { id: 5, commonName: "Abalone Pearls" },
        { id: 3, commonName: "Abalone Shell" }
      ]
    },
    {
      B: [
        { id: 41, commonName: "Barite" },
        { id: 42, commonName: "Bastnaesite" }
      ]
    }
  ];
```

Now by the use of `keyvalue` you can use the following in your template:

```
<div *ngFor="let items of getItems">
    <div *ngFor="let entry of items | keyvalue">
        <div *ngFor="let subEntry of entry.value">
            <div>{{subEntry.id}} : {{subEntry.commonName}}</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use double quotes around your `ngFor` in order to work:

```
<div *ngFor="let items of gemItems">
```